# Integrating a measure with respect to itself

Tags: integration, measure-theory, radon-nikodym

Take a measure space $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, P)$, with $P$ being a probability measure.
I want to construct a second measure from $P$ via  $Q(E) := \int_E P(\omega) \; dP(\omega)$. In other words, I would like to construct a probability measure $Q$, which is equivalent to $P$, such that the Radon Nikodym derivative of $P$ w.r.t. $Q$ remains $P$ (or as close as possible), in a sense that we would integrate $P$ as $P(\omega) = P(\{\omega\})$, to view $P$ as a measurable function on $\Omega$.

Does anyone have any ideas ? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: According to your definition, $P(\omega) = P(\{ \omega \})$.  If $P$ is a non-atomic measure, then $P(\omega) = 0$ for all $\omega$ and therefore the measure $Q$ will just be the zero measure.

Comment: If by $Q(E) := \int_E P(\omega) \; dP(\omega)$ you mean $Q(E) := \int_E P(\{\omega\}) \; dP(\omega)$, then the Radon Nikodym derivative of $P$ w.r.t. $Q$ is the function $f$ such that $f(x) = P(\{x\})$.